# Python Scipy Stats Rayleigh distribution parameter estimate function gives negative value for scale parameter and ppf function provides nan output

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, scipy.stats

I'm using Rayleigh distribution to estimate the scale parameter and getting negative vlaue althoguh the dataset doesn't contain any negative value. What does that negative value mean? If I have negative value, then the ppf gives nan output.

```
from scipy.stats import rayleigh

def baseline_rayleigh(data):
    pd = rayleigh.fit(data)
    B = pd[0]
    return B

p = 0.1
B = baseline_rayleigh(data)
ThreshL = rayleigh.ppf(1 - p, scale=B)
```

For same data, Matlab rayleigh function gives non-negative value and getting valid output from raylinv function whereas the python equivalent rayleigh.ppf gives nan output.

```
pd = fitdist(data,'Rayleigh')
B = pd.B;
ThreshL = raylinv(1-p,B);
```

Answer (score 0):

`rayleigh.fit(data)` [returns](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L7792) a 2-tuple `location, scale`. Simple fix:

```
B = pd[1]  # instead of pd[0]
```

You cal also improve the estimate by fixing the location parameter:

```
pd = rayleigh.fit(data, floc=0)
```

Two-parameter Rayleigh distribution is explained [here](https://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Ekundu/two-par-rayleigh-final.pdf). Note that it defines the scale parameter differently, as \lambda = 1/2 \sigma^2.  `scipy` estimates and returns \sigma, not \lambda